# XmlPath picking preceding/parent attribute

Tags: java, xpath, rest-assured

Given the following XML snippet:

```
<Holiday ItineraryId="123456789" Country="ES" NumberOfNights="7" LeadInPricePerPassenger="447.3" FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="false" Currency="GBP" BookingChannel="WEB" PassengerIdRequired="false" PassengerIdMandatory="false" NationalityRequired="false" NationalityMandatory="false">
    <Flight OriginAirport="LGW" DestinationAirport="ALC" MultiLegOutboundFlight="true">
          <OutboundSubSegments DeparturePoint="LGW" DepartureDate="20180802" DepartureTime="0920" ArrivalPoint="OSL" ArrivalDate="20180802" ArrivalTime="1225" OperatingCarrier="DY" OperatedBy="Super Air Shuttle" FlightNumber="HY637" OriginAirportName="London Gatwick" DestinationAirportName="Oslo" />
   </Flight>
</Holiday>

<Holiday ItineraryId="9283873737" Country="ES" NumberOfNights="7" LeadInPricePerPassenger="447.3" FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="false" Currency="GBP" BookingChannel="WEB" PassengerIdRequired="false" PassengerIdMandatory="false" NationalityRequired="false" NationalityMandatory="false">
    <Flight OriginAirport="LGW" DestinationAirport="ALC" MultiLegOutboundFlight="true">
          <OutboundSubSegments DeparturePoint="LGW" DepartureDate="20180802" DepartureTime="0920" ArrivalPoint="OSL" ArrivalDate="20180802" ArrivalTime="1225" OperatingCarrier="DY" OperatedBy="Super Air Shuttle" FlightNumber="HY637" OriginAirportName="London Gatwick" DestinationAirportName="Oslo" />
   </Flight>
</Holiday>

<Holiday ItineraryId="894847463" Country="ES" NumberOfNights="7" LeadInPricePerPassenger="447.3" FlightOnly="true" OneWayOnly="false" Currency="GBP" BookingChannel="WEB" PassengerIdRequired="false" PassengerIdMandatory="false" NationalityRequired="false" NationalityMandatory="false">
    <Flight OriginAirport="LGW" DestinationAirport="ALC" MultiLegOutboundFlight="true">
          <OutboundSubSegments DeparturePoint="LGW" DepartureDate="20180802" DepartureTime="0920" ArrivalPoint="OSL" ArrivalDate="20180802" ArrivalTime="1225" OperatingCarrier="DY" OperatedBy="Super Air Shuttle" FlightNumber="HY637" OriginAirportName="London Gatwick" DestinationAirportName="Oslo" />
   </Flight>
</Holiday>
```

When I need to extract a List of *all* ItineraryIds based on the child element Flight having an attribute of  MultiLegOutboundFlight="true"

How can I write an XmlPath to achieve this?  I'm using RestAssurred and am experimenting but finding it hard to find resources online for XmlPath syntax so am fumbling blind:

If I do the following:

```
public List<String> getMultiLegFlightItineraryIdList() {
    XmlPath xmlPath = new XmlPath(response.asString()); if(xmlPath.getNode("Holiday.Flight").getAttribute("MultiLegOutboundFlight").equals("true")) {
        String itineraryId = xmlPath.getNode("Holiday").getAttribute("ItineraryId");
        System.out.println(itineraryId);
    }
    return itineraryIDList;
}
```

Then I receive the following error:

```
[Fatal Error] :2:802: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
ERROR:  'The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.'

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert XML to Java Object. If 
you're trying convert to a list then use the getList method instead.
```

Originally I had the following:

```
allMultiLegPackages = response.xmlPath().getList("Holiday.Flight.findAll{it.@MultiLegOutboundFlight=='true'}//parent::Holiday");
```

This returns the list of all Holidays where the condition is true but how to get the attributes ItineraryID's as the list?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Xpath for your parent node,

```
//flight[@multilegoutboundflight='true']//parent::holiday
```

What you need to additionally add is, method which will retrieve inner attribute. Just like by passing `getAttribute('ItineraryId')`

Answer (score 0):

The below snippet might help you.

```
String itineraryId = "";
XmlPath xmlpath = new XmlPath(responseXML);
if(xmlpath.getNode("Holiday").getNode("Flight").getAttribute("MultiLegOutboundFlight").equals("true")) {
    itineraryId = xmlpath.getNode("Holiday").getAttribute("ItineraryId");
    System.out.println("Itinerary ID ::: "+itineraryId);
}
```

Import:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.path.xml.XmlPath;
```

Comment: thank you both.  I explained the problem badly but you have helped.  I actually have an XML Response body with *multiple* Holidays. What I need is a List of ItineraryID's.  I have adapted the code and the question.

Comment: You are getting that error because xml response should have only one root node.

Comment: ok, so my original problem stands - how do I extract the list of ItineraryIDs (attributes)?  I understand I can use getList but I don't know the syntax for the XPath/XmlPath